# How can I correctly use an if-condition along with a for-loop in Twig 3.x?

Tags: theming, 10

The Upgrade Status module tells me this code is no longer valid for Drupal 10 but I'm not sure how that needs to be changed.

```
{% for paragraph in card_page.entity.field_paragraphs if not break %}
  {% set _paragraph = paragraph.entity %}
  {% set _paragraph_type = paragraph.entity.type.entity %}
  {% if _paragraph_type.id == 'landing_hero' %}
    {% set break = true %}
    {% set image_id = _paragraph.field_image.0.entity.id %}
    {% set image_file = file_url(_paragraph.field_image.0.entity.uri.value) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 10 updated Twig from 2.x to 3.x. The `{% for ... if ... %}` statement is removed from Twig 3.x.

In Twig 3.x put the if statement outside the loop or in the loop body:

```
{% set break = false %}
{% for paragraph in card_page.entity.field_paragraphs %}
  {% if not break %}
    {% set _paragraph = paragraph.entity %}
    {% set _paragraph_type = paragraph.entity.type.entity %}
    {% if _paragraph_type.id == 'landing_hero' %}
      {% set break = true %}
      {% set image_id = _paragraph.field_image.0.entity.id %}
      {% set image_file = file_url(_paragraph.field_image.0.entity.uri.value) %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

See the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/3256890

Comment: It's worth noting that in some cases (not this example though) you might be better off using the Twig filter https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html on the for loop. This is especially true if you are using the loop variable inside for.

Comment: I think the IF is inside the FOR loop; not outside. Not the same thing.

Comment: Different things, but the old statement could be used for both. The linked CR has an example for the second one.