# New for/if requirements in twig break bc of additional condition

Tags: blocks

Our content editors have the option of placing a button block in layout builder with a series of buttons on two rows if checkbox is checked. If checked, the value is "On". This worked in Drupal 9 with the "if empty" coupled with the "for" loop, but new requirements in D10 are to separate this out. When we do this it negates the two row request and puts all the buttons on the second row. How can we reimplement the 2nd row option with the new for/if separated as required? Here's our code:

```
 {# if two rows is "on", counts number of button fields w/ url content uses number to loop through and separate into rows #}
        {% if "On" in content.field_two_rows.0 %}
            {% set btn_count = 0 %}
            {% for button in content.field_button_link %}
                {% if button['#url'] is not empty %}
                    {% set btn_count = btn_count + 1 %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            <div class="row two-btn-row btn-row-one">
            {% for button in content.field_button_link %}
                {% if button['#url'] is not empty %}
                    {% if loop.index <= (btn_count / 2) %}
                        <div class="col-md mt-4">
                            <a{{btn_attribute.addClass(btn_classes)}} href="{{ button['#url'] }}">
                                {{ button['#title']|striptags('<i>')|raw }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="row two-btn-row btn-row-two">
                {% for button in content.field_button_link %}
                    {% if button['#url'] is not empty %}
                        {% if loop.index > (btn_count / 2) %}
                            <div class="col-md mt-4">
                                <a{{btn_attribute.addClass(btn_classes)}} href="{{ button['#url'] }}">
                                    {{ button['#title']|striptags('<i>')|raw }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="row one-button-row">
                {% for button in content.field_button_link %}
                    {% if button['#url'] is not empty %}
                    <div class="col-md mt-4">
                        <a{{btn_attribute.addClass(btn_classes)}} href="{{ button['#url'] }}">
                            {{ button['#title']|striptags('<i>')|raw }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: Which new requirements in D10 are you referring to?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/316574/how-can-i-correctly-use-an-if-condition-along-with-a-for-loop-in-twig-3-x

Comment: @cilefen, It's really a Twig 3.x update and is about the move of an if statement inside a for tag to it's separate line https://www.drupal.org/node/3256890

Comment: @4uk4 I did read that article and wasn't sure how to apply that to my situation.

Comment: This is a question on Twig 3 syntax?